# Get a string output using Rply throws ParserGeneratorError: Expecting :

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, ply

Trying to implement parser using rply its just like ply

```
#Input = ['ABC']
lg = LexerGenerator()
lg.add('String', r'\D')

l = lg.build()
for token in l.lex('ABC'):
  print(token)
```

Generated Lexer by above code

```
class String(BaseBox):
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value 
  def eval(self):
    return self.value


from rply import ParserGenerator
pg = ParserGenerator(
# A list of all token names, accepted by the parser. 
     ['String']
)
@pg.production('program: String')
def program(p):
    return p[0].value

parser = pg.build() #should parse string 'ABC'
```

> ParserGeneratorError: Expecting :

Confused this isn't even in the documentation, please reply.
 Want my output to read the stringn as 'ABC'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code indicates that you tested the lexer. However, the test indicates that the lexer is not producing the correct tokens:

```
>>> for token in l.lex('ABC'):
...   print(token)
... 
Token('String', 'A')
Token('String', 'B')
Token('String', 'C')
```

The expected output would have been

```
Token('String', 'ABC')
```

The reason you're splitting on individual characters is that your pattern for recognising `String` only matches a single character:

```
lg.add('String', r'\D')
```

Probably you wanted something more like

```
lg.add('String', r'\D+')
```

But note that `\D` matches anything which is not a decimal digit, including whitespace, punctuation and control characters. Perhaps that is what you wanted, but it seems a bit too permissive to me.

---

Unrelated, but you'll have to fix this as well: as far as I know, RPLY (like Ply) requires you to write grammar rules with spaces around the colon, so your parser function needs to be

```
@pg.production('program : String')
def program(p):
    return p[0].value
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for a quick reply it now throws a new error that IndexError: list index out of range
'.

Comment: Also please help me by upvoting the answer I need just two more reputations to upvote your answer. :)

Comment: When does it give you that error? If it happened when you called `pg.build()`, make sure that the parser function was correctly annotated (`@pg.production(...)`). If you're doing this in a notebook or console session, make sure it's a fresh session. (It's better to keep the grammar code in a file, because you can't reliably build a parser twice in the same session.)

Comment: It happens when  I called pg.build( ). Could you point out what the exact parser fn annotation should be for now it shows list out of range at the annotation side. Saying that p[1] isn't available.

Comment: The code in your question is fine, except for two things: (1) the regular expression needs to be changed as I indicated and (2) RPLY requires you to write the grammar rule with spaces around the colon: `@pg.production('program : String')`. But you really need to put that in a file and `import` it into your console session. I repeat from my last comment, **you can't reliably build a parser twice in the same session**.

Comment: I am using a notebook. I exported the same code to another notebook `parser.parse(tokens).eval()` throws as error ParsingError: (None, None) @rici

Comment: However, `parser.parse(lexer.lex('NN'))` parsed succesffuly and generated the output `NN`